# How to I draw an upwards pyramid with an array?

Tags: java

I need to draw two pyramids using character in arrays. Upwards and Downwards. I have the downwards pyramid but can't think of the upwards.

I can do the downwards pyramid but can't figure the upwards(normal pyramid).

this is the downward of my code

```
        char [] [] pointDown = new char [length] [length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {

                if ( i > 0 && j-i<0)  {
                    pointDown[i][j] = ' ';
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }else if ( j >= length-i){
                    pointDown[i][j] =' ';
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
                else {
                    pointDown[i][j] = asterik;
                    System.out.printf("%2s",asterik);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }        
        return pointDown;
    }
```

my attempt of upward pyramid:

```
        char [] [] pointUp = new char [length] [length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                if ( i > (length-1)/2)
                {             //bottom half spaces
                    pointUp[i][j] =' ';
                    System.out.print("x  ");     
                }else if( j < (length-1)/2 && i < (length-1)){

                }


            }        
            System.out.println();
        }
        return pointUp;
    }
```

3rd update

```
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                pointUp[i][j] = ' ';
            }
        }

        int end = length; 
        int j = 0;
        for (int column = 0; column < end; column++) {
            for (int row = j; row <= length/2; row++) {
                pointUp[row][column] = asterik;
            }
            j++;
            end++;

        }
        return pointUp;
```

Comment: Can you include your code for your attempt at the upwards pyramid?

Comment: i just did. it not even close. the "x" is just to visualize the space

Comment: you could just revers your downwards array by rows :)

Comment: could you pls show how?

Comment: Your loop for upwards should be the same as your loop downwards. All you need to do is change the contents of the ```if``` and the ```else``` depending on whether its upwards or downwards. Remember, both pyramids do the same thing, each just has stars where the other one has spaces.

Comment: i tried switching but didn't work

Comment: What exactly did you try? Can you update your attempt code above?

Comment: i updated the second code